# KeyError: Django Losing Session Data Between CBV Redirects

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, django-sessions

When I redirect to another view after adding data, specifically stripe Customer data, to a dict that is then added to my session, I lose *all* of the information in my session at the redirected view. Thus, I encounter a KeyError when I try to pop these items.

Interestingly, this does not happen when I put other types of information in my payment_data dict, like a list instead of a customer object.

I'm not sure what's the best way to fix this problem, but given what I have designed, it's important for me to get the Customer information to the confirm view so that I can

1. List item
2. Display customer information to the user for confirmation (censoring sensitive information
3. Charge the card

This is my code:

```
   class PaymentsCreateView(FormView):
       def form_valid(self, form):
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(description="""
            Non-registered user for applying features""")
        customer.save()

        payment_data = {
            'customer': customer
        }

        self.request.session['payment_data'] = payment_data
        self.request.session.modified = True

        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace();

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('payments_confirm'))

class PaymentsConfirmView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'payments/confirm.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PaymentsConfirmView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['payment_data'] = self.request.session.pop('payment_data')
        context['feature_data'] = self.request.session.pop('feature_data')

        return context
```

I'm still debugging and my next step is to confirm whether the issue is that I am trying to store a Customer object rather than a dictionary or list object but maybe someone on SO can confirm or supply the right answer.

Comment: Instead of `self.request.session.pop()` do `self.request.session.get()`.

Comment: But the key doesn't exist in the session in the first place, so what difference does it make in terms of which method I use in acquiring the data?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.pop([i])
>
> Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in the list.

Like Rohan says, use `get()`:

```
context['payment_data'] = self.request.session.get('payment_data', False)
context['feature_data'] = self.request.session.get('feature_data', False)
```